# file is not converting in excel 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have following code.I want to generate excel in .xlsx for excel 2010 or higher using c# asp.net but unable to generate My code is following

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Students.xlsx";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
            excel.RenderControl(htextw);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stw.ToString());
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/css/main.css"));
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText();
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
            }
            sr.Close();
            Response.Write("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" + sb.ToString() + "</style></head>" + stw.ToString() + "</html>");
            stw = null;
            htextw = null;
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

Guide me How I open my file in excel 2010

Comment: What do you mean _unable_ ? Is it error ? Is it not generated ? Is it not be able to be opened on client ?

Comment: its generated when i used .xls extention

Comment: Maybe you have an error on CType ? try application/vnd.openxmlformats instead of application/application/vnd.openxmlformats (application is writed twice) See https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20deliver%20an%20Excel%20file%20in%20ASP.NET%3f&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I have not download epplus file for this

Comment: Is there a warning popup on client browser or just nothing happened?

Comment: warning popup when I used this ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Comment: but when i changed the contentype getting error

Comment: try changing the content type to `application/vnd.ms-excel` or I think it's a typo, you have two `application` in `application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: I copy this in a website

Comment: No its also not working application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet